# How to uninstall deprecated Unsubscribe plugin from Mail.app?

Tags: mail.app, plugins

I used the Unsubscribe plugin for Mail.app, but it is now a part of TrustedID (http://www.unsubscribe.com/), so now I can't use it anymore and want to remove it.

When I want to uninstall the plugin from inside the Mail.app preferences, nothing happens when I hit the button `Remove Unsubscribe Plugin`. There's nothing in /Users/*MyUserName*/Library/Mail/Bundles that looks like the Unsubscribe plugin.

How to uninstall deprecated Unsubscribe plugin from Mail.app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UnsubMailPluginMail App for OS X is a leftover from a free program which later switched to become a user pay software. The program vanished but the plugin stayed to pop up and annoy you.

To remove it:

1. Open your Finder window.
2. Proceed to the `Go` menu.
3. Then down to `Go to Folder...`.
4. Then in the window delete existing wording and type in
   `/Library/Mail/`.

When the folder opens, locate the plugin and move it to Trash.

Comment: Reformatting this as a series of discreet steps (1, 2, 3...) would make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

It's not in your Home folder. Look in the Library folder on the main level of your hard drive. ([Macintosh HD/Library/Mail/Bundles] Replace "Macintosh HD" with the name of your hard drive.)

Comment: No, the folder in the main Library is empty.